Memurai .exe not starting with error "Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:6379: listen: Invalid argument"
I am trying to run memurai.exe on the powershell and its failing with the error "Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:6379: listen: Invalid argument."
A standalone older redis-server.exe file however is still able to run on the machine. Port 6379 was open and listening. I see the same error in the event viewer log.

What actual command did you run?

What command are you using for running Memurai ? Also have you tried a different port ?
Might also be an external problem such as firewall/antivirus; could try turning those off.
Running the console in admin mode is another consideration.

The PowerShell command used-
/memurai.exe
Powershell is running as an administrator and we did try running this on a different port by explicitly providing the port option -
/memurai.exe --port 7502
We also disabled the antivirus running the VM and still couldn't get it to start up.
